# Aurelia creating a Binding Behaviour that wraps SignalBindingBehaviour

Tags: data-binding, aurelia

I've currently got a simple Value Converter which uses `momentjs` to convert Dates to strings:

```
export class MomentValueConverter {
  public toView(value: Date, format: string): string {
    return moment(value).format(format);
  }
}
```

However, wherever I use it I end up having to combine it with the `aurelia-translation-signal` so that its updated if the user changes the current language.

```
${fileSaved | moment:'ll LTS' & signal:'aurelia-translation-signal'}
```

How do I instead create a Binding Behavior that automatically takes care of the signalling from `aurelia-translation-signal`?

Then I could use it like:

```
${fileSaved & moment:'ll LTS'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good example in aurelia-i18n library, https://github.com/aurelia/i18n/blob/master/src/t.js#L89-L122

```
import {ValueConverter} from 'aurelia-binding';
import {SignalBindingBehavior} from 'aurelia-templating-resources';

export class TBindingBehavior {
  static inject = [SignalBindingBehavior];

  constructor(signalBindingBehavior) {
    this.signalBindingBehavior = signalBindingBehavior;
  }

  bind(binding, source) {
    // bind the signal behavior
    this.signalBindingBehavior.bind(binding, source, 'aurelia-translation-signal');

    // rewrite the expression to use the TValueConverter.
    // pass through any args to the binding behavior to the TValueConverter
    let sourceExpression = binding.sourceExpression;

    // do create the sourceExpression only once
    if (sourceExpression.rewritten) {
      return;
    }
    sourceExpression.rewritten = true;

    let expression = sourceExpression.expression;
    sourceExpression.expression = new ValueConverter(
      expression,
      't',
      sourceExpression.args,
      [expression, ...sourceExpression.args]);
  }

  unbind(binding, source) {
    // unbind the signal behavior
    this.signalBindingBehavior.unbind(binding, source);
  }
}
```

UPDATE: Signals are internally supported by value converters already http://aurelia.io/docs/binding/value-converters#signalable-value-converters

```
import {signalBindings} from 'aurelia-framework';

signalBindings('locale-changed');


export class FlightTimeValueConverter {
  signals = ['locale-changed'];

  toView(date) {
    return date.toLocaleString(window.currentLocale);
  }
}
```

Comment: try to put the example in the answer instead of just the link. Links can become outdated

Comment: @valichek am I right in saying there is a new way to do this?

Comment: @Tim please, explain what you mean?

Comment: @Tim nice catch, I will add the link to the official doc